# Suggestion needed for package names

Tags: java, naming

I have a couple of packages I have trouble naming.

- This package contains classes and interfaces for communicating with external servers through client software. The external servers are not part of our system, but required for daily operations.
- This package contains classes and interfaces that import and export data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on  who is going to use this package? Other teams  or is it internal? Draw the tree structure that you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping it simple, and naming them `your.app.external` and `your.app.importexport`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking to a specific service, I would just name it after the service.  So if you were using `com.mycompany` as your namespace, and you were talking to the Floobulator service, I might just call it something simple like `com.mycompany.floobulator`

As far as import and export, I often don't put it in its own package, unless there is a reason to.  In that case, try out `com.mycompany.floobulator.import` `.export` or perhaps `.io`?  Just use whichever one "feels right" as this is probably not a terribly huge decision in the long run as long as it is somewhat sensible.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about naming them after services, but where should I put those classes used by multiple services?